# Background colour with alpha transparency

Tags: html, css

If i have a div with this kind of CSS:

```css
background: #000000;
```

Can i then also apply a transparency amount to the background colour only, which won't effect the borders OR the content within the div ? So it only effects the background colour? I don't want to use a `.png` background if I can help it, so wondered how its done if at all.

Also if it is supported is it supported in all browsers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use RGBa:

```
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
```

[RGBa browser support](http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this..
It may work in all browser:

```
.class_name {
zoom: 1;
filter: alpha(opacity=50);
opacity: 0.5;
}
```